# Validation customer address attribute in Backend and Frontend server side

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, customer-address

I should create a server side validation for a customer_address attribute in both the backend and the frontend.

I do not use overwrite the model and the `validadateData()` method associated to the attribute because being a validation that must also take into account other fields in that method are not passed (correct me if I'm wrong, maybe it's usual in this case to work with the Request)

For the Frontend validation I use the event: `customer_address_validation_after`

For backend validation, since that event is not triggered but only passes from the single validation of the attributes, I use the predispact event of the validateAction controller used in the backend.

Is it correct as a solution to the requirement? is there a more recommended way?
thanks a lot